# Advantage of Pod Over Containers

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I have read a lot of kubernetes documents but couldn't get a answer. In kubernetes architecture the basic component is a pod. Why did it make an abstraction layer over container to create a pod and manage it rather than managing the container directly. What are the main advantages kubernetes gets by managing pod rather than an container.

what is the task of the wrapper over the container ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in officail documentation [Understanding pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#understanding-pods) have a nice description about

> Pods in a Kubernetes cluster can be used in two main ways:
>
> **Pods that run a single container**. The “one-container-per-Pod” model is the most common Kubernetes use case; in this case, you can think of a Pod as a wrapper around a single container, and Kubernetes manages the Pods rather than the containers directly.
>
> **Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together**. A Pod might encapsulate an application composed of multiple co-located containers that are tightly coupled and need to share resources. These co-located containers might form a single cohesive unit of service–one container serving files from a shared volume to the public, while a separate “sidecar” container refreshes or updates those files. The Pod wraps these containers and storage resources together as a single manageable entity.

If you think of **Pods that run a single container** then  you might think maintaining container is more reasoning, but in second case **Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together** might face more complexity

Comment: thanks. I read that and wanted the answer to the why on the "Pods that run a single container". What extra does the wrapper do in this scenario. What is the task of the wrapper.

Comment: You run a pod with single container, in future you want to set some extra features directly not related to container service, but adding sidecar, like  a proxy to help manage traffic and terminate TLS, a container for streaming logs and metrics, or a container that scans for security issues. You can easily do that by injecting as sidecar into the pod. Only limiting single container it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

The containers of a pod will always be together, and they can communicate using the loopback interface. Pods allow you to deploy closely coupled components together as separate containers. For instance, you can bundle an app and a proxy for that app that adds an encryption layer together so encrypted traffic goes in and out of the app without modifying the app container.

Comment: Thanks, but in the general accepted concept one pod has one container, so the above reasoning doesn't help much.So if say kubernetes mandated one container in one pod do we not need pod and can use containers directly

Comment: @SnehasishDas There are many scenarios where one pod has more then one container. IE proxying outgoing requeqsts to a cloud database. Pod and containers are NOT interchangable ideas, so you cannot choose one or the other

Comment: There are cases where you need multiple containers in a pod. I once worked on a project where we had to connect the service via tls. Since we could not modify the apps running in the pods, we added additional containers into those pods to add tls tunneling.  You could not do that if pods do not support multiple containers.

Comment: @SnehasishDas, things like istio work by injecting extra containers into pods.